# How to write specific line lengths of a file?

Tags: python, file

I have this sequences (over 9000) like this:

```
>TsM_000224500 
MTTKWPQTTVTVATLSWGMLRLSMPKVQTTYKVTQSRGPLLAPGICDSWSRCLVLRVYVDRRRPGGDGSLGRVAVTVVETGCFGSAASFSMWVFGLAFVVTIEEQLL
>TsM_000534500 
MHSHIVTVFVALLLTTAVVYAHIGMHGEGCTTLQCQRHAFMMKEREKLNEMQLELMEMLMDIQTMNEQEAYYAGLHGAGMQQPLPMPIQ
>TsM_000355900 
MESGEENEYPMSCNIEEEEDIKFEPENGKVAEHESGEKKESIFVKHDDAKWVGIGFAIGTAVAPAVLSGISSAAVQGIRQPIQAGRNNGETTEDLENLINSVEDDL
```

The lines containing the ">" are the ID's and the lines with the letters are the amino acid (aa) sequences. I need to delete (or move to another files) the sequences below 40 aa and over 4000 aa.
Then, the resulting file, should contain only the sequences within this range (>= 40 aa and <= 4K aa).

I've tried writing the following script:

```
def read_seq(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as file:
        return file.read().split('\n')[0:]

ts = read_seq("/home/tiago/t_solium/ts_phtm0less.txt")

tsf = open("/home/tiago/t_solium/ts_secp-404k", 'w')

for x in range(len(ts)):
    if ([x][0:1] != '>'):
        if (len([x]) > 40 or len([x]) < 4000):

            tsf.write('%s\n'%(x))

tsf.close()

print "OK!"
```

I've done some modifications, but all I'm getting are empty files or with all the +9000 sequences.

Comment: You could try using Biopython, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for loop, `x` is an iterating integer due to using `range()` (i.e, `0,1,2,3,4...`). Try this instead:

`for x in ts:`

This will give you each element in `ts` as `x`

Also, you don't need the brackets around `x`; Python can iterate over the characters in strings on its own. When you put brackets around a string, you put it into a list, and thus if you tried, for example, to get the second character in `x`: `[x][1]`, Python will try to get the second element in the list that you put `x` in, and will run into problems.

EDIT: To include IDs, try this:

NOTE: I also changed `if (len(x) > 40 or len(x) < 4000)` to `if (len(x) > 40 and len(x) < 4000)` -- using `and` instead of `or` will give you the result you're looking for.

```
for i, x in enumerate(ts): #NEW: enumerate ts to get the index of every iteration (stored as i)
    if (x[0] != '>'):
        if (len(x) > 40 and len(x) < 4000):
            tsf.write('%s\n'%(ts[i-1])) #NEW: write the ID number found on preceding line
            tsf.write('%s\n'%(x))
```

Comment: Without the [] I have this:

if (x[0:1] != '>'):
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Did you change the for loop to `for x in ts:`?

Comment: Oh! Now I'm getting closer. I removed all of them and got the sequences but not the ID's.

Comment: If you want the IDs, remove the `if` statement filtering out lines that start with `>`... But I thought that was what you wanted?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I have not explained it well. I need the ID's and it's following sequences, I just have to eliminate the sequences (and respective ID's) below 40 aa and over 4K aa.

Comment: Thank you, you've helped me not only on writing the code but in understanding better how the language works!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, simple and easy to understand. It does not load the entire file into memory, instead iterates over the file line by line.

```
tsf=open('output.txt','w') # open the output file
with open("yourfile",'r') as ts: # open the input file
    for line in ts: # iterate over each line of input file
        line=line.strip() # removes all whitespace at the start and end, including spaces, tabs, newlines and carriage returns.
        if line[0]=='>': # if line is an ID 
            continue # move to the next line
        else: # otherwise
            if (len(line)>40) or (len(line)<4000): # if line is in required length
                tsf.write('%s\n'%line) # write to output file

tsf.close() # done
print "OK!"
```

FYI, you could also use awk for a one line solution if working in unix environment:

```
cat yourinputfile.txt | grep -v '>' | awk 'length($0)>=40' | awk 'length($0)<=4000' > youroutputfile.txt
```

Comment: Nice. I liked they way you wroted it but now I'm getting this error: 
SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop

Comment: That might be because of an indentation error during copy paste. However, you can refactor the code, to change the if condition to line[0]!='>' and do else portion, and that will get rid of continue.

Comment: Thank you for your tips! Like I said to the other buddy, you helped me to understand better the language too.